# ConcurrentModificationException happen for findAllById in arangodb-spring-data with concurrent workers

Tags: java, spring-data, arangodb, concurrentmodificationexception

When I try to build up an java app to retrieve data from ArangoDB based on [ArangoDB-spring-data library](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data), there was always an exception happen ConcurrentModificationException when calling `SimpleArangoRepository.findAllById` with concurrent workers, why? Does this meet expectations? Then what's the best practice to call the `findAllById` in a concurrent environment?

The detailed call process is as follows:
//The goal is to find whether the given items are already existing in the database or not. and this check would be called by multiple workers with different IDs.

```
List existingTiles = new ArrayList<>();
tileRepo.findAllById(tileIds.stream().map(String::valueOf).toList()).forEach(existingTiles::add);
```

The call stack for the exception is as following:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1229)
at com.arangodb.springframework.core.mapping.DefaultArangoPersistentEntity.findAnnotations(DefaultArangoPersistentEntity.java:269)
at com.arangodb.springframework.core.mapping.DefaultArangoPersistentEntity.getIndexes(DefaultArangoPersistentEntity.java:242)
at com.arangodb.springframework.core.mapping.DefaultArangoPersistentEntity.getPersistentIndexes(DefaultArangoPersistentEntity.java:210)
at com.arangodb.springframework.core.template.ArangoTemplate.ensureCollectionIndexes(ArangoTemplate.java:166)
at com.arangodb.springframework.core.template.ArangoTemplate._collection(ArangoTemplate.java:159)
at com.arangodb.springframework.core.template.ArangoTemplate._collection(ArangoTemplate.java:139)
at com.arangodb.springframework.core.template.ArangoTemplate._collection(ArangoTemplate.java:132)
at com.arangodb.springframework.core.template.ArangoTemplate.findAll(ArangoTemplate.java:484)
at com.arangodb.springframework.repository.SimpleArangoRepository.findAllById(SimpleArangoRepository.java:135)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
```

Comment: I suppose you can wrap your method in a synchronized block or use some other form of synchronization/locking